Confused about use of Euler totient function in RSA
I'm reading a book and I arrived at the part that explains 'textbook' RSA. It explains that given a modulus $n=pq$ and public exponent $e$ that we can encrypt $x \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}_n$ by setting $y=x^e \bmod n$. The secret exponent $d$ is related through
$$y^d \bmod n\ = (x^e)^d \bmod n\ = x^{e\,d} \bmod n\ = x$$
It then says that this implies that $$e\,d\bmod \phi(n)=1$$ (where $\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$ )
I don't understand:

why $x^{ed} \bmod n =x$ implies that $e\,d\bmod \phi(n)=1$ ?
How do we encrypt a message $x \notin \mathbb{Z}^{*}_n$ ?


What is the source of this question? Including the page number and book addition in the question is always better for the community.



why $x^{ed} \mod n =x$ implies that $ed\mod \phi(n)=1$?


Answer: it doesn't.
On the other hand, if $\forall x: x^{ed} = x \pmod n$, that does imply that $ed \bmod \text{lcm}(p-1, q-1) = 1$.
If $ed \mod \phi(n) = 1$, that also implies that $ed \bmod \text{lcm}(p-1, q-1) = 1$ (because $\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)$ is a multiple of $\text{lcm}(p-1, q-1)$), however the converse is not true (unless $p$ or $q$ happens to be 2).
As for the "why" behind what I stated, well:
$\forall x: x^{ed} = x \pmod n$ implies that $\forall x: x^{ed} = x \pmod p$ and $\forall x: x^{ed} = x \pmod q$ (Chinese Remainder Theorem); those two imply that $ed = 1 \pmod{p-1}$ and $ed = 1 \pmod{q-1}$ (converse of Fermat's Little Theorem), and both of those implies that $ed = 1 \pmod {\text{lcm}(p-1, q-1)}$ (Chinese Remainder Theorem again).
Actually, each step is an equivalence, and so the beginning and ending statements are equivalent.


How do we encrypt a message $x \notin \mathbb{Z}^{*}_n$?


Two answers:

$\forall x$ includes values of $x \notin \mathbb{Z}^*_n$, that is, we can use the standard RSA encrypt/decrypt algorithms without issue.
In practice, it never arises; both $p$ and $q$ are huge values, and so the probability of us picking an $x$ that happens to have one of them as a factor is neglectable.

BTW: it would appear that the book you're reading is either deliberately providing a simplified (and somewhat incorrect) explanation, or the author is clueless.  I would suggest that, in either case, if you're actually interested in learning how RSA works, you find a better source.

Note: this answer assumes $n=p,q$ with $p$ and $q,$ distinct primes. This is the case in RSA, either as a requirement, or with overwhelming certainty because $p$ and $q$ are large and mostly independent random primes.

@fgrieu: actually, if $p=q$, then $\forall x: x^{ed} = x \pmod{pq}$ implies that $ed=1$, and hence $ed \bmod \text{lcm}(p-1,q-1)= 1$ is still true (albeit we don't have equivalence in that case)
